# Word for low level noise among restless crowd, as sign of confusion or complaint?

Tags: single-word-requests

Dictionary gives me "drone" and "murmur" but I'm not sure if that's the word I am thinking of.  I want to use it to describe a group of people on strike who hear that their demands are not met and the CEO has resigned.  They're not shouting, but they're not whispering either.  They're restless and confused.  I want to say that a certain something (murmur?) was heard among the crowds, to indicate their state.

Comment: Crowds also "clamor," but this is not a low-level noise. It is loud.

Comment: murmor fits the situation very well for me.. But  I'd say a murmor spread through the crowd.  Or a murmor trembled through the room...

Comment: I've also heard "angry murmur" and "nervous murmur"   (and drat that spelling above)

Comment: The technical term in media for this is _[walla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walla)_.

Comment: Someone else had to think of this, right?
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gSQg1i_q2g
RABBLE RABBLE RABBLE

Comment: Actually I thought of this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NmgA5ef5K8s

Comment: Younglings, the lot of you, it's actually [rhubarb](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=55Zdvj1pLp8).

Answer (score 55):

I think you were spot on with **murmur** as suggested in the question:

> A low continuous background noise:
>   *‘the distant murmur of traffic’*

([Oxford Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/murmur))

A more relevant example could be:

> The murmuring crowd was distracting the speaker.

Or, as a noun:

> A murmur of agreement spread through the crowd at the suggestion.

Comment: This was played to effect in "Young Frankenstein" when the Angry Mob literally said "murmur, murmur". (With my avi, I should be expected to make YF references.)

Answer (score 28):

"a rumbling of discontent" may work.

[Rumbling](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/rumbling): synonym of rumble:

> - a deep, heavy, somewhat muffled, continuous sound
> - a widespread murmur of discontent

[Discontent](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/discontent):

> - dissatisfaction

Comment: Please flesh out your answer by adding relevant definitions from a dictionary, and adding usage examples.

Comment: I like rumbling.  You just need to document it a little bit.

Comment: Ngram likes [wave of discontent](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=a+rumbling+of+discontent%2Ca+wave+of+discontent&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ca%20rumbling%20of%20discontent%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ca%20wave%20of%20discontent%3B%2Cc0) better. There's also *murmurous discord* and *dissension in the ranks*.

Comment: @ANonymouse - You are asked to flesh out with *relevant* definitions, not irrelevant ramblings. I've removed your edits and added in relevant definitions.

Comment: @AndyT the upvote definitely goes towards your edit, if I had known beforehand what a sulky and churlish explanation had originally been give, I'm not so sure I would have upvoted. Anyway, this is the answer I had in mind, *rumble* expresses a sense of foreboding. The ground *rumbles* just before an earthquake, does it not?

Answer (score 25):

The word you're looking for is **mutter**. The [Oxford Living Dictionary](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/mutter) has, as a noun:

> A barely audible utterance, especially one expressing dissatisfaction or irritation.

And as an example for the verb:

> Back-benchers were muttering about the next reshuffle.

Comment: A crowd can murmur, but can it mutter? For some reason it sounds odd with a mass noun, but I'm not sure why.

Comment: @Matt A Google search for "the crowd was muttering" turns up abundant results. Besides, the OP asks for a noun. "A mutter rose from the crowd" fits.

Comment: +1 for including the desired negative connotations.  I've definitely heard of a "crown muttering".

Comment: It seems a little odd to me to say that "the crowd was muttering", but you could certainly say that there was "muttering among the crowd".

Comment: My take: A low mutterance. A growing mutterance. A low but growing mutterance. (its a word, at least on https://en.oxforddictionaries.com)

Comment: Personally, I like "commotion."

Comment: While this is a great word to bring up, I agree that mutter is something an **individual** does.  (It's totally commonplace that dictionaries, particularly non-OED< are stupid.  Regarding finding usages, you can find millions of usages of "aks" for "ask".)

Answer (score 12):

I asked an online thesaurus for [synonyms of *clamor*.](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/clamor?s=t)
Perhaps one of these would suit for the murmuring crowd:

- buzz
- brouhaha
- hubbub

> There was a [buzz/brouhaha/hubbub] as the CEO's resignation was announced.

Comment: *hubbub* and *brouhaha* both have the same problem as *clamor*: they're much louder than *murmur* or *drone*. Furthermore, they do not refer just to sound. They mean "uproar" and includes the sense of "ado" or "fuss": making a big deal over a trivial matter. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brouhaha.

Comment: In the link you cited, *hubbub* and *brouhaha* refer to controversies, not the volume. Since they refer to "a state of social agitation," I think they capture the "restless and confused" notion that the OP is seeking.

Comment: I like hubbub but the dictionary defines it as "chaos, bedlam, mayhem" - I've always thought it was only a very low state of these things more like "bustling, burbling or murmuring".

Comment: hubbub and murmur needn't be discontented. You could have a happy hubbub of people chatting quietly in a queue. Similar with murmur. Muttering is usually discontented. A buzz is more likely to be positive - 'there was quite a buzz about the new piece in the auditorium'. A brouhaha is more of an altercation.

Comment: 'as' or 'when'?

Comment: These are excellent suggestions. With any SWR there is the issue of the subtlest shade of meaning.

Answer (score 10):

What about "hubbub"?

There was a certain *hubbub* among the crowd.

[Hubbub](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hubbub), from M-W.com:

> Noun - a loud mixture of sound or voices
>   : a situation in which there is much noise, confusion, excitement, and activity

Comment: -1 A hubbub seems way too much for the asker's requirements. It's pretty loud.

Comment: @DCShannon - While it can be loud, I've found in usage it's not necessarily very loud.  [Here's another definition](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/hubbub), and [another](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/hubbub): "a mixture of continuing noises producing a feeling of busy activity or confused excitement" ...so it's certainly noise, then I guess it'd be how loud you define "noise".  (Again, not saying I disagree, but it's not necessarily super loud).

Answer (score 9):

***Susurration*** — [Vocabulary.com](https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/susurration)

> (noun) 1. the indistinct sound of people whispering
>   speaking softly without vibration of the vocal cords

Example from [Laumer, Keith](http://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/21782)

> The pipes and reeds were shrilling furiously, and the susurration of Yillian conversation from the other tables rose ever higher in competition.

Comment: Welcome to ELU. We're looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context. Don't just give a one-line answer; explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations

Comment: @AndrewLeach this is what I was talking about in meta. The automatic vote.

Answer (score 9):

**Grumble**-According to [**Merriam-Webster**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/grumble)

> :to mutter in discontent
>   : to complain quietly about something : to talk in an unhappy way
>   : to make a low, heavy sound

- *the crowd grumbled their annoyance*
- *could hear the grumbling among the crowd*
- *a soft grumble spread through the crowd*

Answer (score 5):

For me a [din](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/din) has always had a negative connotation:

noun

[in singular] A loud, unpleasant, and prolonged noise:
    ‘the fans made an awful din’

Answer (score 1):

The word **stir** could be used here. For e.g.

> The crowd began to **stir**.

Meaning in this context:

> **stir**: a commotion.
>
> e.g. "the event caused quite a stir"

Comment: If this is a quote from a reference work, please cite the work.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the word ***hum***.

ODO:

> **[hum](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/hum)**
>   *NOUN*
>
> **1** [in singular]
>   A low, steady continuous sound:
>   ‘a low hum of conversation’
>
> There were wounded who groaned in their sleep or called out, and there
>   was the soft, steady hum of conversation among the wounded who could
>   not sleep.’

Answer (score 1):

***dull roar***

> a relatively quiet degree of noisiness

Neat that it is an oxymoron describing the muted (typically loud) noise of a crowd

http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/dull+roar

Answer (score 1):

**Din** may be the a good fit for what you describe, it's more than a low-grade murmur, but lacks the edginess of a clamor.

Answer (score 1):

You could use "***chatter"*** , see examples of usage in the Oxford Living Dictionary https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/chatter

Chatter does not imply a restless or confused state but it does convey animated conversation below the threshold indicating uproar.

Answer (score 1):

A **discordant murmuration** was heard among the crowds.

discordant:

> a:  being at variance, disagreeing, as 'discordant opinions';
>   b: quarrelsome, as 'a discordant family'
>   [[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/discordant)

murmuration:

> the act of murmuring:  the utterance of low continuous sounds or complaining noises, as 'the murmuration of the crowds' — A. E. Richardson; 'ceaseless, inarticulate murmuration of prayer' — Frederic Prokosch
>   [[Merriam-Webster]](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/murmuration)

Answer (score -4):

I like the use of murmur, one common idiom phrase I didn't see above was, **hush**:

> "a hush fell over the audience."

Meaning: a sudden silence enveloped something or a group. As the conductor raised his arms,  The coach shouted and a hush fell over the locker room. *-- thefreedictionary.com*

Comment: A hush would be the opposite of a murmur. A murmur is sound. A hush is the absence of sound.