# Word for sound of a crowd talking all around you

Tags: single-word-requests

*murmur* is one I'd use for a low voice talking crowd. I'm looking for more alternatives.

Comment: Related question and helpful synonyms: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/369046/word-for-low-level-noise-among-restless-crowd-as-sign-of-confusion-or-complaint

Comment: Have you tried a thesaurus?

Comment: nattering and grommishing (look up "The Trouble with Tribbles")

Comment: @Mitch Got links for a resource where I could search for this rather than ask here? Other than Google, which I already tried.

Comment: @rajah9 thank you for the really good related link :).

Comment: I see there are 4 close-votes for this one, even though there is a tag called "single word requests". I'd appreciate if those that voted "close" can illuminate me to what's missing, so that I may correct the question or not ask it next time :).

Comment: [Thesaurus.com](http://www.thesaurus.com/) is a great starting place for this kind of question. I think you'll find almost all of the suggestions from answers in [its entry on *murmur*](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/murmur?s=t), for example. (That's probably the reason for at least some of the close votes—a thesaurus is considered a "general reference".)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**hum**

bustle, buzz

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hum?s=t

**hubbub**

a loud, confused noise, as of many voices

http://www.dictionary.com/browse/hubbub?s=t

Comment: I think hubbub is the best. It specifically implies "a chaotic din caused by a crowd of people." (This definition is via the snippet at the top of the Google results page.)

Comment: buzz itself works too.

Answer (score 15):

I like **din**

:  a loud continuous noise, especially of discordant sounds [Webster's]

*I could barely hear the music over the din of the audience.*

Comment: -1 din suggests a loud noise  not a low voice/talking crowd.

Comment: @Fraser -1 OP said that *murmur* is a word for the noise of a crowd when it isn't tumultuous. He was asking for more words for the noise of a crowd generally. Din is so perfect it was my reply, too; unfortunately Stu posted first.

Comment: No the op is looking for alternatives to murmur - Din isn't 'perfect' as  it suggests a loud, discordant noise and has nothing specifically to do with crowds

Comment: OP's question and text match completely. He's looking for words for crowd noise. Murmur is one, but particularly a low-volume form. It's really not hard to understand, hence this being the most upvoted reply.

Comment: People like coldplay and voted for the Nazis - it could have a billion upvotes and it wouldn't make it correct.

Answer (score 4):

**Susurration** is a nice choice, if there is a whispering quality to people's vocalizations. Groups of people around you can make many different sounds.  It depends upon the specifics of what's happening and how people are feeling and acting.  You've gotten lots of good suggestions for various types of sound.

> The crowd **susurrations** were liquid in his screwed-up ears. Cory
>   Doctorow, *The Makers*
>
> [see Fine Dictionary compendium of definitions, etymology and
>   usage](http://www.finedictionary.com/susurration.html) including:
>
> n susurration speaking softly without vibration of the vocal cords
>
> n susurration the indistinct sound of people whispering "a  soft
>   susurrus of conversation"
>
> L. susurratio, fr. susurrare, to whisper: cf. F. susurration,
>   hypernyms :sound, speaking, speech production

Answer (score 3):

I would go for **babble**, which can mean

> a continuous low or confused sound, especially the sound of several people talking

([Cambridge dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/babble))

Comment: +1 Imo, your answer would be a good place to mention ["babel"](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Babel) along with "babble" as a curious example of nearly synonymous homonyms (*babel*'s second pronunciation).

Answer (score 3):

**Tumult**

> disorderly agitation or milling about of a crowd usually with uproar and confusion of voices

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tumult)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say murmur is right, maybe you could use mumble, but it has a different meaning in my oppinion.

Comment: Mumble does have a different meaning.  It is the act of making the sound, not the sound itself.

Answer (score 1):

*Rumor* can also be used in this context:

> a soft low indistinct sound; murmur

<sub>(source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rumor))</sub>

Answer (score 1):

My own preferred word is **susurration**

According to [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/susurration) it means:

> a soft murmur; whisper.

Comment: I chose sussuration too.  I had the answer box open for quite a while in between doing other things & didn't see your answer.  I wasn't trying to poach.

Comment: @Palizsche - no problem at all; these things happen :-)

Answer (score 1):

Three of my favorite words in the English language describe this:

**hubbub** - a busy, noisy situation caused by a crowd of people.

**hullabaloo** - a commotion; a fuss.

**brouhaha** - a noisy and overexcited reaction or response to something.

Out of them all hubbub is specifically a word that describes what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

Well, personally, I like [din](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/52968) since it's always appropriate if the noise of a crowd is unpleasantly loud enough to be noticed in the first place.

As far as things people haven't already mentioned, there's also

## [walla, rhubarb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walla)

> The radio, film, TV, and game industry jargon for indistinct crowd noise.

## [rumble](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/168760), [rumb](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/168772)[ling](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/168761)

> A low, heavy sound, continuous but varying; a murmur, grumble, or growl, esp. of discontent; noises of restlessness, or an early indication of tumult and uproar...

## [rabble](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gSQg1i_q2g)

> A meaningless, rambling or derogatory spiel; babble; a disorderly assembly of people, *esp.* of the lower classes...

## [chatter](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/30969), [chat](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/30975)[tering](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/30971), [chatteration](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/30972)

> A rapid succession of short vocal sounds, *as* some bird calls; rapid, incessant, trivial speech; prattle...

## [natter](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/125322)

> *US* chatter; *Scots* grumbling, nagging speech.

## [rattle](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/158555)

> A rapid succession of short, sharp, percussive sounds; a state of uproar; lively and empty chatter, babble...

Answer (score 0):

A perhaps less obvious, yet colourful choice would be '**dissonance**'.

> **Dissonance**
>  a mingling of sounds that strike the ear harshly
>   a mingling of discordant sounds; especially, music

Source: [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/dissonance)

Comment: That term describes the tonal qualities of the noise being created by the crowd. It's not really a name for the noise itself.

Comment: No it doesn't. It's a "mingling of sounds". Each voice is a sound and they have mingled.

Comment: Disson*ant* would be a quality.