# Phrase to describe a crowd all speaking at once

Tags: word-choice

Looking for some phrase to describe a crowd all speaking at once - like at press conference when all trying to get a question in. Or when a speaker makes a statement the crowd all speak at once in response etc

Comment: perfect - thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for sound of a crowd talking all around you](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/386679/word-for-sound-of-a-crowd-talking-all-around-you)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Roar_of_the_Greasepaint_%E2%80%93_The_Smell_of_the_Crowd